# Keyboard properties window not coming to front in WPF App

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a button in my WPF application which is opening keyboard properties but in some random cases keyboard properties open behind main application window. I can't understand why this is happening. I have also used SetForegroundWindow() to bring it to front but still same happening.

Comment: When you debug, whether the keyboard properties open on top of your main application window or behind??

Comment: @Sivasubramanian on the top of app

Comment: Can you post the code snippet which you are trying to open the keyboard properties??

Comment: IntPtr handle = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("main.cpl","@1,2").MainWindowHandle;
SetForegroundWindow(handle)

Comment: Hi, you said "but in some random cases keyboard properties open behind main application window", What do you mean by that?? can you tell me those cases??

Comment: The app which starts the keyboard properties is a foreground process or background process??

Comment: @Sivasubramanian its a foreground process

Comment: A friend of mine test it and he told that its happening, he may have set main application always remain on top.